# Anyone Please help me to find how to mock a database by using mockito

Tags: java, database, testing, mocking, mockito

I am new to unit testing. I want to know how can I use mockito framework to mock database. I am sick of searching. Please help me with this.

Comment: Please show us what you have attempted so far. Please ask specific questions which we will happily try to volunteer time to answering. Have you made any attempt at solving this yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't 'mock a database' as you say. The purpose of a mocking framework is as follows:

Imagine you have a method called `myMethod()` which calls some 3rd-party methods which you trust to be working, hence are not under test.

You tell the mocking framework:

- when `myMethod()` calls `thirdPartMethod1()` with parameters x and y it will return z
- `myMethod()` will call `thirdPartyMethod2()` 4 times with parameters a,b,c,d respectively. If it does not, please fail the test.

So the mocking framework will itself take the place of the 3rd party methods and return what it is told to when you set it up, e.g. it will return the expected result when `myMethod()` calls `thirdPartMethod1()`.

It will also check that the calls are as expected, e.g. that `thirdPartyMethod2()` is indeed called the correct number of times with the correct parameters.

So, when you mock the Database calls, you are **not** really calling the database. You can tell the Mockito to create a mock based on the JDBC ResultSet interface, for instance, and tell it what to return when called with certain parameters, and how many times methods on it will be called and what parameters the methods will be called with. The actual database and the real JDBC implementation are not involved at all.

If you really must use the database, consider [DBUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: The problem is I need to test method according to the result that come from the database. How can I test that?

Comment: You mock a ResultSet and tell Mockito to return the desired result when you call getXXX() where XXX is whatever type you want, e.g. getInt(), getString() etc

Comment: @NickJ nice answer couldn't say it better myself

Comment: Please Can you give me sample code of miking result set it is really helpful to me

Comment: Here you go: https://www.assembla.com/code/henrico/subversion/nodes/example%20project/test/za/magmatec/henrico/example/DAO/jdbc/employment/EmployerJDBCDAOIntegrationTest.java?rev=9